# Using one view model in multiple windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I use **one view model** for **many windows in WPF**? I need model to be updated from one window only and handle these changes in others (for ex. property 'Locked').

I have one view model incapsulating the most general info that should be used not only on the A (suppose it is 'Company') window but also on windows child window B (suppose it is 'Person'). So the 'General' view model should be determined by A entity but be passes to all children entity. While updating this view model on A window - we should se changes on all B windows.

```
public partial class A : WindowBase
{
    private GeneralViewModel general;
    public GeneralViewModel General
    {
        get
        {
            return this.general ?? (this.general = new GeneralViewModel ());
        }
    }
}

public partial class B : WindowBase
{
    private GeneralViewModel general;
    public GeneralViewModel General
    {
        get
        {
            return this.general ?? (this.general = new GeneralViewModel ());
        }
    }

    public B(GeneralViewModel g)
    {
        this.general = g;
    }
}
```

I wish the model should be updated only in A and B was simply displaying that changes were maid. In case I pass model as it is shown in this code or if I implement 'General' as property with getter and setter changes are not applied.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [singleton-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) as your ViewModel.

Example:

```
 public Window()
 {
     this.DataContext = ViewModel.Instance.
 }
```

EDIT:

```
public GeneralViewModel
{
     public DataType Model
     {
         get { return DataType.Instance; }
     }
}
```

Now everytime you access the Model in one of your GeneralViewModels, it is locked for all others.

Comment: Sorry but I should be able to create multiple A windows eigher. So that each A has its own GeneralViewModel. (Suppose A is a company and B - people, if A is locked B are locked either).

Comment: Than make just the model a singleton. Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your view model in a static member somewhere and have the windows return the value as their `GeneralViewModel`.

Comment: I should be able to multiple instances of A window. So one instance could be locked and another one not. Child windows refer to concrete A entities and be also locked or not.
I don't understand how static member can help me.

Comment: @Julia Given that you have so finely encapsulated your view model properties, you _will_ have to change your window code. The static property should return your view model, the windows should be instanced as usual.

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you mentioned, your `GeneralViewModel` is a kind of `Dependency` to both your `Window` classes and for these purposes you can use some of the available `IoC containers` or `MEF` built into `.Net 4`. You can register your `Dependencies` including the `GeneralViewModel` in some application startup event.

Below is some sample code that will make your `GeneralViewModel` instance to be then located from the container it is registered with (MEF in below case):

```
[Export(typeof(B))]
public partial class B : WindowBase
{
    private GeneralViewModel general;
    public GeneralViewModel General
    {
        get
        {
            return this.general ?? (this.general = new GeneralViewModel ());
        }
    }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public B(GeneralViewModel g)
    {
        this.general = g;
    }
}
```

> To learn more about `MEF`,see these articles:

- [CodePlex](http://mef.codeplex.com/)
- [Ten Reasons to use the Managed Extensibility Framework](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/ten-reasons-to-use-managed.html)
- [Managed Extensibility Framework Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [An Introduction to Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) - Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188054/An-Introduction-to-Managed-Extensibility-Framework)

There are many other DI and IoC containers available as Open Source downloads.

Comment: Shouldn't I add anything else? Now changes are not reflected on view as well.
Look like I need to call 'RaisePropertyChanged' after assignment for all properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem if you use MVVM. In this case your ViewModel will correspond to some View which is basically the UserControl and you can place it to as many Windows as you wish.
And When you implement MVVM you should also use INotifyPropertyChanged or ObservableCollections